# Multiple seam sets for multiple UV maps?

Tags: uv, unreal-engine

Since I am using Blender to create static meshes for UE4 I have to produce two different UV unwraps of the same object. One for texturing etc. and one for the lightmap. Two different UV maps are needed because the requirements are very different.

Because of this I have to cut the object differently. Is there a way to define two different sets of seams for the two different UV maps?